# Javascript indexOf/charAt not working for Japanese half-width Katakana

Tags: javascript, string, indexof, cjk, charat

In my codebase I have this code, surprisingly it returns 1:

```
'ﾄｹﾞ'.indexOf('ｹ') // Returns 1
```

The character `ｹ` doesn't seem to appear in string `ﾄｹﾞ`.

I also tried to run this code:

```
'ﾄｹﾞ'.charAt(1)  // Returns `ｹ`
```

And to my surprise it returns `ｹ`.

Can you explain why the codes above return 1 and `ｹ`? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string consists of three characters: ﾄ, ｹ and ﾞ. [There is no dedicated halfwidth-ge character](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf), you'll always use a regular halfwidth character and add the halfwidth voiced sound mark to it, which will be rendered as the combined glyph ｹﾞ.

Note that there *is* a dedicated fullwidth ゲ KATAKANA LETTER GE U+30B2.